# navigator.notification.alert iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova

My alert on ios project doesn't work. I'm using ionic and angularjs to develop my app.

The problem is that when alert is show, the title is "index.html". Actually I call alert like this:

```
alert("aaa");
```

I read that cordova allows to change title, using navigator.notification.alert. But the alert is not show when I call it.

I call alert as below:

```
.controller('MyCtrl',function(){
$scope.myfunction = function(){


    var success = function(data){
     //do something
};

var failure = function(message){
   navigator.notification.alert(
                                         "This is my Alert text!",
                                         callBackFunctionB, // Specify a function to be called
                                         'Alert Title',
                                         "OK"
                                         );
};

function callBackFunctionB(){
            console.log('ok');
            }

}

});
```

I add plugin and add key in infoplist following instructions in phonegap documentation.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: When do you call "$scope.myfunction" ?

Comment: when I press a button that open camera

Comment: Is "navigator.notification" defined?

Comment: where and when I define it?

Comment: Try if (navigator.notification) {console.log("navigator.notification defined");}...else console.log("navigator.notification undefined");

Comment: Run "cordova plugin list" and edit your question to sshare the output

Comment: notification plugin was in the list, but i've tried to remove that and reinstalled and now it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to remove plugin and reinstall it and now it work.